# Comparative Study on Retention Rate

Tags: user-research, usability-testing, mobile-application

Our competitor has a very similar App with almost identical features and use cases. We know that he has better retention rates. What is the best way to find out why? One idea I have is to find users who don't know any of the apps and evaluate both Apps independently. But would this deliver comparative data?

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy answer to this, but one strategy would be to perform [competitive analysis using the SUM method](https://www.measuringu.com/papers/HCII2005_sauro_kindlund-V9.pdf). This would give you insight into which use cases and tasks are better or worse across products, as well as an overall metric to compare products. If you record those usability tests you run within the SUM methodology, you may also discover some product pain points qualitatively.

Comment: Thank you, the SUM methodology was new to me. As another point of view, I would be interested in a more qualitative approach and keep this question open to gather some more inspiration for study design.